# Error 0x8007025D while making usb windows 10 install

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

When I try to install windows 10 from a pen drive I get an error with this code: 0x8007025D. I downloaded the iso with windows 10 media creation tool and tried downloading it multiple times.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit: downloading the iso from MCT and then flashing the usb drive with Rufus worked!

Answer (score 1):

That error normally means the ISO media is damaged in some way. Try downloading it again to see if that works. You might try making the ISO on a different machine.

[Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/error-code-0x8007025d-while-trying-to-install/a27d88cf-cb84-4bb4-a21f-32c56144f3ef)

> From my experience with multiple ISOs of Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 and even
> 10, I can tell you that error 0x8007025d means that the installation
> media is corrupted.
>
> This kind of error appears on **official Media Creation Tool from
> Microsoft too.**
>
> The issue appears most likely when choosing Windows 8.1 (Not N or
> PRO).
>
> The issue could be fixed only by downloading the same or another ISO
> image again. Also, flashing it again on the USB or burning it on
> another DVD by using a SLOWER speed may increase the success rate.